# First Fetch API call cancelled by the second in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, fetch-api

I have a ReactJS application that works as expected in Chrome, but fails in IE-11.

The problem is this - we have two drop down lists which are populated from rest services when the page is first loaded. The application is running under SSL. When the page is loaded through IE-11, I get an IE-11 bug issue where the first request call gets cancelled out by the second-the bug is described here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/1282036/

So, I am just asking the community whether there is a work around for IE-11 or is there away to implement my code sequentially where if the first is complete the second is called:

```
export let getMainData = (dtType, url)=> {
    return dispatch=>{
           dispatch(sendGet(dtType));
           const action = (async(url) => {
                  const response = await fetch(url);
                     let data = await response.json();
                        dispatch(receiveGet(dtType,data));
         });
       action(url);
     };
};
```

The code above is common code and is used by others in the React App. So what I am thinking if there is away to have a level of abstraction where the two drop down lists can call sequentially and then call the above underneath, perhaps?

Answer (score 31):

Just include `isomorphic-fetch` as polyfill to make it work on unsupported browsers.

https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out, fetch is not supported by IE11, I also had this problem in my React app. You can, alternatively, use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

If you are migrating (or can migrate), check [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50326744/1042409) to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844297/what-is-difference-between-axios-and-fetch/50326744#50326744)

Basically, check this code:

**Fetch JSON post request**

```
let url = 'https://someurl.com';
let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                property_one: value_one,
                property_two: value_two
            })
        };
let response = await fetch(url, options);
let responseOK = response && response.ok;
if (responseOK) {
    let data = await response.json();
    // do something with data
}
```

**Axios JSON post request**

```
let url = 'https://someurl.com';
let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            data: {
                property_one: value_one,
                property_two: value_two
            }
        };
let response = await axios(options);
let responseOK = response && response.status === 200 && response.statusText === 'OK';
if (responseOK) {
    let data = await response.data;
    // do something with data
}
```

I always have main request function that the app uses, so it doesn't matter if you use fetch or axios. For example in 'your-common.js':

```
async function request(url, method, objectData){
    // use axios or fetch or isomorphic-fetch
}
```

So if your complete app is using your request function, you simply change the library in that function and no harm is done as long as you return the same object or value. You can also wrap the fetch (or axios or whatever http library you use) in a try/catch block to handle promises if using async/await.

Comment: keep in mind axios doesnot work well with streams. fetch does but fetch does. Also using polyfills can make it work on IE11, 10 and 9 too. here is the link mentioning the same thing.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/

Answer (score 3):

Unrelated to ReactJS, but I hope useful to others who land here as I did.

I found the [Github fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch/releases) and [TaylorHakes' Promise polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) nice and easy to get started with in the context of my ASP.NET MVC web application.  Both were recommended by [https://ourcodeworld.com](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/625/top-5-best-javascript-polyfills-for-the-fetch-api)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which is not supported yet by IE. That's why your app works on Chrome.

I would suggest you moving to a 3rd party lib such as Axios, superagent, etc...

Comment: I thought this will be the case but it is a little too late for me to change libraries

Comment: Is there a way to handcraft a solution for this as it is only affecting two dropdownlists

Comment: you could change the libs for these two dropdowns only... later you can change all other places if you're short on time

Comment: Can you please explain why if I add setTimeout it forces it to work?

Comment: I have no clue. Do you have any polyfills for the fetch API?

Comment: No polyfill. Did you have a look at the link I gave from Microsoft

Comment: create-react-app template uses whatwg-fetch, this is a wrapper of the fetch api and should support all browsers, but i have the same problem, the fetch is not working at all on IE 11

Answer (score 1):

IE dont offer suport for the fetch use.
You need use some polyfill for solve this problem.
You can use http://github.github.io/fetch/.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165483) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)