# What is difference between Axios and Fetch?

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I'm trying to call a web service for my application, and there are **two options available: Fetch and Axios. I'm not sure which one to choose**, so I'm looking for information to help me decide. Can you explain the **differences between the two and their advantages**? I'd appreciate it if you could keep your explanation simple and easy to understand.

Comment: I think this has been discussed in a great detail over https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/314

Comment: Although there are many answers but I find nobody mentions the request timeout that axiso has over fetch.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Fetch and Axios are very similar in functionality, but for more backwards compatibility Axios seems to work better (fetch doesn't work in IE 11 for example, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258632/react-fetch-not-working-in-ie11))

Also, if you work with JSON requests, the following are some differences I stumbled upon with.

**Fetch JSON post request**

```
let url = 'https://someurl.com';
let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                property_one: value_one,
                property_two: value_two
            })
        };
let response = await fetch(url, options);
let responseOK = response && response.ok;
if (responseOK) {
    let data = await response.json();
    // do something with data
}
```

**Axios JSON post request**

```
let url = 'https://someurl.com';
let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            data: {
                property_one: value_one,
                property_two: value_two
            }
        };
let response = await axios(options);
let responseOK = response && response.status === 200 && response.statusText === 'OK';
if (responseOK) {
    let data = await response.data;
    // do something with data
}
```

So:

- Fetch's **body** = Axios' **data**
- Fetch's body has to be **stringified**, Axios' data contains the **object**
- Fetch **has no url** in request object, Axios **has url** in request object
- Fetch request function includes the **url as parameter**, Axios request function **does not include the url as parameter**.
- Fetch request is **ok** when response object contains the **ok property**, Axios request is **ok** when **status is 200** and **statusText is 'OK'**
- To get the json object response: in fetch call the **json() function** on the response object, in Axios get **data property** of the response object.

Comment: Here is more question. Once responseOk is true, do we need to check the status in response.data if it has status provided? thanks

Comment: `Axios request is ok when status is 200 and statusText is 'OK'`

What about other httpStatus in the 2xx range like 201 or 204?

Comment: or I think `response.ok` is a boolean, and the `true` or `false` value indicates whether response was ok. User offline is handled by the `fetch()` rejecting, but other types of server error is handled by `response.ok`

Answer (score 85):

They are HTTP request libraries...

I end up with the same doubt but the table in this [post](http://andrewhfarmer.com/ajax-libraries/) makes me go with `isomorphic-fetch`. Which is `fetch` but works with NodeJS.

http://andrewhfarmer.com/ajax-libraries/

---

The link above is dead
The same table is here: https://www.javascriptstuff.com/ajax-libraries/

Or here:
[image]

Comment: Still I am not able to find the benefit of fetch over axios. Can you have any idea why I should go with the axios?

Comment: I have found some of the difference as:-                                        Overall they are very similar. Some benefits of axios:

Transformers: allow performing transforms on data before request is made or after response is received
Interceptors: allow you to alter the request or response entirely (headers as well). also perform async operations before request is made or before Promise settles
Built-in XSRF protection

Comment: I think fetch is a standard see https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/ ... axios could have more features because it doesn't follow that.... I think in the end they do the basics (ajax http request) but it depends on what you need... I didn't need a transformer ... so getting a standard lib is a pro...

Comment: Be aware that [that table](http://andrewhfarmer.com/ajax-libraries/) is misleading. It defines `fetch` as **Native** (_Meaning you can just use it - no need to include a library_, accordingly to the table source), while actually `fetch` is [not implemented in some platforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) (notably in all versions of IE), for which you need to provide an external polyfill anyway.

Comment: Adding to the difference mentioned by @jack123 fetch also doesn't provide a basic ajax functionality like `timeout` (which is very weird) we have to use a separate module to implement this basic functionality.

Comment: @LucasKatayama fetch is not a library. It is a method present on the window object. It serves the same purpose an XMLhttpRequest object serves, but is more composable as is it Promise based. Now, Axios is a library. You need to import it into your application using CommonJS's require, or use import, if use are using a node application or using node modules.

Comment: @APJ Is it safe to say "axios API" like people say "fetch API" ? and why is fetch called an API?

Comment: @JohnAnisere axios is not an API. It is just another library. It is a promise based HTTP client. axios is not available on the window object of the browser. Go to your console and see it for yourself. Type "this.fetch". You'll be able to see the returned function. Now try doing "this.axios". You'll see 'undefined' because it is not directly available on the window. You need to install it using bower, npm or using the cdn in your application. It is safe to call fetch an API because it is directly attached to the window, like the ServiceWorker API.

Comment: @CoderPJ How an API is implemented isn't relevant, though; all libraries have an API. You can't randomly assume `this.fetch` will be meaningful, e.g., IE: https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch.

Comment: @LucasKatayama The link appears to be broken

Comment: The link is dead. I wish the actual answer was in your response

Comment: @tamj0rd2 just posted another link.

Comment: [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) is very good, but not maintained as [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is. Latest commit for isomorphic was on may 2016... latest commit for axios, 15 hours ago. Axios has more contributors, more examples, basically better help. That's why I kept axios before isomorphic-fetch.

Comment: Note that fetch API is fully supported by NodeJS since version 18.0.0.

Answer (score 45):

According to **mzabriskie** [on GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/314#issuecomment-217346581):

> Overall they are very similar. Some benefits of axios:
>
> - Transformers: allow performing transforms on data before a request is made or after a response is received
> - Interceptors: allow you to alter the request or response entirely (headers as well). also, perform async operations before a request is
>   made or before Promise settles
> - Built-in [XSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) protection

please check Browser Support Axios

[image: browser support table]

I think you should use axios.

Comment: Agreed. Axios is also small enuff import so that bloat is not much concern - as opposed to something like express or mongoose where if one is a bit insane about package size, they might be concerned. :)

Answer (score 23):

One more **major difference** between fetch API & axios API

- While using service worker, you have to **use fetch API only** if you want to intercept the HTTP request
- Ex. While performing caching in PWA using service worker you won't be able to cache if you are using axios API (it works only with fetch API)

Comment: Can anyone verify this is really true?    It is 1 person, but the 9 upvotes seem to agree yet it would be nice to see comments on this   ( I'm using axios with service worker pwa offline is why I ask.

Comment: Sure, we can have few more comments on this but I was facing issues with caching while using axios and when I replaced axios with fetch() APIs it got resolved

Comment: This seems to be correct, but might be fixed in a near future:
https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/2891

Answer (score 13):

1. Fetch API, need to deal with two promises to get the response data in JSON Object property. While axios result into JSON object.
2. Also error handling is different in fetch, as it does not handle server side error in the catch block, the Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing. While in axios you can catch all error in catch block.

I will say better to use axios, straightforward to handle interceptors, headers config, set cookies and error handling.

[Refer this](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5)

Comment: I think this is one of the biggest differences, thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 12):

Benefits of axios:

- Transformers: allow performing transforms on data before request is made or after response is received
- Interceptors: allow you to alter the request or response entirely (headers as well). also perform async operations before request is made or before Promise settles
- Built-in XSRF protection

[Advantages of `axios` over `fetch`](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/314)

Answer (score 12):

Axios is a stand-alone 3rd party package that can be easily installed into a React project using NPM.

The other option you mentioned is the fetch function. Unlike Axios, `fetch()` is built into most modern browsers. With fetch you do not need to install a third party package.

So its up to you, you can go with `fetch()` and potentially mess up if you don't know what you are doing OR just use Axios which is more straightforward in my opinion.

Comment: Fetch is ok, but Axios is like you said - more straightforward.   That which is built into modern browsers (fetch) isn't that great for feature releases.    -  so I prefer Axios

Answer (score 5):

In addition... I was playing around with various libs in my test and noticed their different handling of 4xx requests. In this case my test returns a json object with a 400 response. This is how 3 popular libs handle the response:

```
// request-promise-native
const body = request({ url: url, json: true })
const res = await t.throws(body);
console.log(res.error)


// node-fetch
const body = await fetch(url)
console.log(await body.json())


// Axios
const body = axios.get(url)
const res = await t.throws(body);
console.log(res.response.data)
```

Of interest is that `request-promise-native` and `axios` throw on 4xx response while `node-fetch` doesn't. Also `fetch` uses a promise for json parsing.

Comment: @baitun these are from me running unit tests which (I think I was using Mocha) often have a `.throws` method to test errors thrown. In this case I was testing rejections from al 3 libs and noticed the difference in the data that was returned.

Answer (score 2):

Axios is an HTTP client library based on promises whereas Fetch is a javascript API for making API requests.

1. The Main difference is browser support: Axios supports all browsers including IE whereas Fetch is supported by the latest browser only and IE does not support it.

Reference link:https://github.com/axios/axios#browser-support

https://caniuse.com/fetch

2. Axios has better error handling compare to fetch API. Axios can throw 400 to 500 range status code errors whereas in fetch API you need to manually handle the errors.
   For more: https://bariablogger.in/f/axios-vs-fetch-react

Answer (score 2):

## fetch

fetch is a native API available in modern browsers. "Native" in the context of browser APIs means that the feature is built into the browser's JavaScript environment without the need for external scripts or plugins. It's a standard part of the environment. For instance, fetch is now a standard part of the Web Platform API, which modern browsers aim to support. It's like how XMLHttpRequest (which gave rise to AJAX) is native to browsers, even if it wasn't always the case. For fetch, while it's native to modern browsers, it's true that older browsers like IE require a polyfill (a script that provides the functionality of a newer feature in older browsers that don't natively support it).

Pros:

- Native: Doesn't require any additional packages or libraries to use.
- Promise-based: Easily use with async/await.
- Readable syntax: Especially for simple GET requests.

Cons:

- Error Handling: Doesn't reject on HTTP error statuses (e.g., 404 or 500) but only on network errors or request failures.
- Features: Some advanced features (like request timeout, request cancellation) are not natively supported or require additional work.
- JSON Parsing: Requires an additional step to parse JSON (response.json()).

---

### axios

axios is a popular third-party HTTP client library.

Pros:

- Error Handling: Rejects the promise on HTTP error statuses, which can simplify error handling.
- Interceptors: Provides the ability to intercept requests and responses before they are handled or sent.
- Timeouts: Built-in support for request timeouts.
- Cancellable Requests: Supports request cancellation using the CancelToken feature.
- Automatic JSON Parsing: Automatically parses JSON data from responses.
- Wider Browser Support: Has built-in XHR handling which provides compatibility with older browsers.
- Transforms: Allows data to be transformed before it's sent or after it's received.

Cons:

- External Dependency: Adds an additional dependency to your project.
- Size: While not massive, it's still larger than the native fetch.

Answer (score 0):

With fetch, we need to deal with two promises. With axios, we can directly access the JSON result inside the response object data property.

Answer (score 0):

A job I do a lot it seems, it's to send forms via ajax, that usually includes an attachment and several input fields. In the more classic workflow (HTML/PHP/JQuery) I've used `$.ajax()` in the client and PHP on the server with total success.

I've used axios for dart/flutter but now I'm learning react for building my web sites, and JQuery doesn't make sense.

Problem is axios is giving me some headaches with PHP on the other side, when posting both normal input fields and uploading a file in the same form. I tried `$_POST` and `file_get_contents("php://input")` in PHP, sending from axios with FormData or using a json construct, but I can never get both the file upload and the input fields.

On the other hand with Fetch I've been successful with this code:

```
var formid = e.target.id;

// populate FormData
var fd    = buildFormData(formid);       

// post to remote
fetch('apiurl.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: fd,
  headers: 
  {
     'Authorization' : 'auth',
     "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest"
  }
})
```

On the PHP side I'm able to retrieve the uploads via `$_FILES` and processing the other fields data via $_POST:

```
  $posts = [];
  foreach ($_POST as $post) {
      $posts[] =  json_decode($post);
  }
```