# How to retrieve data from reactjs and API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, isomorphic-fetch-api

I am trying to post form data from react to node backend, How to do thtat ?
my React code is :

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export function createBio (data) {

    console.log(data);

    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/user/create', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {

            'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        }

    }).then(res => {
        return res;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

My NodeJs code

```
router.post('/create', (req,res,) => {

    var user = new User({title: req.params.title || "Untitled Note", body: req.params.body});
    user.save();

});
```

How to retrieve **data**

Comment: console.log `req.params.body`, that's where your data should be

Comment: error **undefined**  :(

Comment: what about `req.body`

Comment: like empty **{}**

Comment: and the data logged in `createBio` is not empty?

Comment: no, it's not empty

Comment: Can you log `req` ?

Comment: Another thing what db that you are using and is there anything return from `user.save()` ?

Comment: undefined, db is mongodb,  no now i am just trying to log this values

Comment: check your network tab for a cors error

Comment: are you setting any 'Access-Control-Allow-Origint' headers on your server?

Answer (score 4):

`req.param()` searches the url path, body, and query string of the request (in that order) for the specified parameter. If no parameter value exists anywhere in the request with the given `name`, it returns `undefined`, or the optional `defaultValue` if specified.

> url path parameters (`req.params`)

e.g. a request `/create/4` to route `/create/:id` has url path params `req.params.id`
:id this id you can change anything you want, but you should add ":" before your parameter

> body parameters (`req.body`)

e.g. a request with a parseable body (e.g. JSON, url-encoded, or XML) has body parameters equal to its parsed value

if you want to get the title, you can write `req.body.title`

For your case, I recommend you use req.body

> Your back-end API

```
//http://localhost:3001/user/create
    router.post('/create', (req,res) => {

    const user = new User(
          {
          title: req.body.title ===null ? 'Untitled Note' : req.body.title, 
          text: req.body.text
          });
    user.save();

});
```

> You should determine what value your data include

```
data = {
title: '?',
text: '?'
};
```

> Your Fetch

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export function createBio (data) {

    console.log(data);

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/user/create', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {

            'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        }

    }).then(res => {
        return res;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

**Make sure of your path is right**

> Any way, I use 'axios' to retrieve data

```
router.post('/'),
    (req, res) => {
        const newPost = new Post({
            eventTitle: req.body.eventTitle,
            eventText: req.body.eventText
        });

        newPost.save().then(post => res.json(post));
    });
```

> axios

```
const postData = {
title: '?',
text: '?'
};
     axios
            .post('/api/posts', postData)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

> Get params

```
**!But this title should be assigned a value. not a null value**


router.post('/:title'),
        (req, res) => {
            const newPost = new Post({
                eventTitle: req.params.title,
                eventText: req.body.eventText
            });

            newPost.save().then(post => res.json(post));});
```

---

```
   const postData = {
    title: '?',
    text: '?'
    };
         axios
                .post(`/api/posts/${postData.title}`, postData.text)
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

> If you have any questions about fetch, you can use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/.

I hope this is useful for you. Actually, I never used fetch, but axios is same with it.

> PS: you should add this for your server.js to get value from the client side.
>   Node.js body parsing middleware. Parse incoming request bodies in a
>   middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body
>   property.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

> **Last answer for your comment and your issue.**

**First, you should add `proxy` to your client side package.json**
You can`npm I concurrently` to run your server and client simultaneously

> Your package.json should include --- I did't create a server json, this may a wrong format. But just a test. The **part** of ** should be written in the server package.json file! If you don't want to use it, you can just focus on the code, it will fix your problem.

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    **"server": "node server.js",**
    **"client": "npm start",**
    **"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",**
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

> `npm I node-fetch` at client side

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
    //import axios from 'axios';
    //import fetch from 'node-fetch';
  import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
    class SendMessage extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                title: '',
                text: ''
            };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const newUser = {
            title: this.state.title,
            text: this.state.text,
        };
        // axios.post('/users/create', newUser)
        //     .then(res => console.log(res))
        //     .catch(err => console.log(err));



        fetch('/users/create', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newUser)
        }).then(res=>res.json())
            .then(res => console.log(res));


    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" name='title' onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.title} placeholder="title"/>
                    <input type="text" name='text' onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.text} placeholder="text"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SendMessage;
```

> Server side server.js

```
const express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



//import route
const users = require('./route');

var app = express();


//Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Use routes
app.use('/users', users);



const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

> Server side route.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/create', (req,res) => {

    console.log(req.body);
    const user =
        {
            title: req.body.title ===null ? 'Untitled Note' : req.body.title,
            text: req.body.text
        };
    res.status(200).json(user);

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: If you have any questions, please leave a message. I will reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3002'

Comment: Let me download fetch npm, wait a second

Comment: Add "proxy": "http://localhost: 3001" to your client package.json
And just fetch('/user/create')

Comment: See the last Answer, I hope it can help you

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a request to '/user/create' when your Node.js server is listening on 'create'. Try changing

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/user/create'
```

to

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/create'
```

Comment: If you have a router like `const userRoute = require('./routes/user');` and add it to your app with `app.use('/user', userRoute);` there is no problem with his code, but we don't know how he set up his server without looking at his server code.

Answer (score 1):

My best way, start create file api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    user: {
        createBio: data => axios.post(`${process.env.API_HOST}/user/create`, {data}).then(res => res),
    }
}
```

and then you can call function createBio from your component or action if you use redux,

if you get problem Access-Control-Allow-Origin use [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware to parse the body of your request

in your server.js:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));
```

and supposing you send an object to the server like:

```
let data = {
    myProp: 'myVal1'
}
```

You can then get it in the request:

```
router.post('/create', (req,res,) => {
    let value = req.body.myProp;
    console.log('value in body: ' + value);
    // execute...
});
```

This will log:

```
value in body: myVal1
```

I would also strongly recommend using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for your requests instead of fetch, and read my answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50326744/1042409) where I discuss some differences and how to implement axios if you are using fetch already. This way you don't need to stringify your data for example, and you solve other issues discussed there.

If you use Axios (with async/await), set your request object like so:

```
let reqObj = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/user/create',
    data:  {
        myProp: 'myVal1'
    }
};
```

And send the request to axios with:

```
let response = await axios(reqObj);
```

Comment: @david if you try this solution, do you get something logged in console? Can you please add your package.json and your server configuration to your question so we can see what else could be going on?