# How to get updated data in React

Tags: reactjs

How to get updated data of react by calling the new data that will be received from another page by ajax?

How to replace new data to "Result" div.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        }  
    $.ajax({
      url:"/test.bc",
      type:"get",
      success:(result)=>{
        this.setState({data: eval(result)});
      }
    })
    $(document).on('update_result',(event,startairline,classname,stops)=>{
      $.ajax({
        url:"/new.bc",
        type:"post",
        data:{
          startairline:startairline,
          stops:stops,
          classname:classname,
        },
        success:(result)=>{
          console.log(result)
          this.setState({hasBeenChanged: true,data:eval(result)})
        },
      })
    });
  }

  renderFlight(){
    return this.state.data.map((item)=>{ 
      return(<input type="hidden" value={item.total} name="total" /> )
    } )}

  render(){  
    return(<div>{this.renderFlight()}</div>  )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Result'));
```

Comment: a couple of questions, why are you using jquery? why ajax and not fetch or axios?

Comment: Also, you cannot call setState in the constructor, have a proper read [at the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Use `componentDidMount` for this.

Comment: Im new in react native, Could you please edit my code?

Comment: don't worry if you are new. Have you already read the link I added?

Comment: Yes,but actually i am confused about componentDidMount. I try to use  componentDidMount() {
    axios.post(`new.bc`,{startairline,classname,stops})
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        this.setState({ data });
      })
  } instead of   $.ajax({
            url:"/new.bc",
            type:"post",.........})  but it doesnot work!

Comment: that is the correct way, why didn't it work? did you get an error message? axios is the best and easiest IMHO. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50326744/1042409)

Comment: Error message :SyntaxError and it is because of componentDidMount(). I try the link you added, but there is the same error about this line : let response = await axios(options);

Comment: please edit your question and add the code with these changes so I can see what is going on. If you use async/await you have to make the function async with `async componentDidMount() {`

Comment: There is a div called Result in my page.By default data of json.bc(json.bc contains json) would be shown in this div , but after checking a checkbox the data of newjson.bc(json) must be represent in Result div and the previous data must be remove and new data must be shown in Result  div.

Comment: <div id="Result"></div>

Comment: <script type="text/babel">
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
          
    };

Comment: $.ajax({
            url:"/json.bc?from=[##cms.query.from##]&to=[##cms.query.to##]&fdate=[##cms.query.fdate##]&tdate=[##cms.query.tdate##]&adult=[##cms.query.adult##]&child=[##cms.query.child##]&select-age=[##cms.query.select-age##]&share=[##cms.query.share##]&userid=[##db.userid.userid##]",
            type:"get",
            success:(result)=>{
            this.setState({data: eval(result)});
            }
            })

Comment: $(document).on('update_result',(event,startairline,classname,stops)=>{
componentDidMount() {
    axios.post(`newjson.bc`,{startairline,classname,stops,from :"[##cms.query.from##]",to:"[##cms.query.to##]",fdate:"[##cms.query.fdate##]",tdate:"[##cms.query.tdate##]",share:"[##cms.query.share##]",userid:"[##db.userid.userid##]",username:"[##db.UserName.answer##]",adult: "[##cms.query.adult##]",childcountandage: "[##cms.query.child##][##cms.query.select-age##]",})
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
        const data = res.data;

Comment: this.setState({data});
      })
  }
       });

  }

Comment: renderFlight(){
  return this.state.data.map((item)=>{
  return(
      <div>{item.id}</div>
   )
}
 
  )
}
render(){
  return(
<div>{this.renderFlight()}</div>
  )
}

}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Result'));

Answer (score 1):

I prepare you an example, using **componentDidMount** and **fetch**:

[Here working](https://codepen.io/ene_salinas/pen/GYwBaj)

```
    let { Table } = ReactBootstrap;

    class Example extends React.Component {
        constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            products: []
        }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount..')
        fetch('https://api.github.com/users/xiaotian/repos')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(output => {
            let products = []
            for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                products.push({selected:false,name:output[i].name})
            }

            this.setState({products},() => console.log(this.state))

        })

        }

        render() {

            return(<Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Selected</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.products.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked={item.selected}/></td><td>{item.name}</td></tr>
                    ) 
                })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>)
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Example />, 
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
```